# Deduce unsolvability of $\operatorname{IP}(G_0)$ from the Adian–Rabin Theorem

Tags: gr.group-theory, graph-theory, algorithms, geometric-group-theory

$\operatorname{IP}(G_0)$: the special isomorphism problem for $G_0$, i.e., given $G_0$, determine if $G$ is isomorphic to $G_0$. My question is that how can we deduce from the Adian–Rabin theorem that $\operatorname{IP}(G_0)$ is unsolvable for any finitely presented $G_0$?
I have found the following paper:

[Stillwell - The word problem and the isomorphism problem for groups](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/bulletin-of-the-american-mathematical-society-new-series/volume-6/issue-1/The-word-problem-and-the-isomorphism-problem-for-groups/bams/1183548590.full)

Is it true to say that Theorem 5, page 53 is derived from the Adian–Rabin Theorem? And if no, do you know a reference including the deduction of unsolvability of $\operatorname{IP}(G_0)$ from the Adian–Rabin Theorem?

Answer (score 3):

The triviality problem (input: a finite group presentation of a group $G$, output: yes/no according to whether $G$ is a trivial group) is not solvable by an algorithm. Indeed just apply the [Adian-Rabin theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adian%E2%80%93Rabin_theorem) to the property "being trivial".

Now we deduce the general case of your question as follows:

Suppose by contradiction that you have an algorithm $A$ whose input is a finite presentation of a group $G$ and output is yes/no according to whether $G$ is isomorphic to the given finitely presented group $G_0$.

Then $A$ solves the triviality problem. Namely input $G$, and apply $A$ to the concatenation of presentations of $G$ and $G_0$, which is a presentation of the free product $G\ast G_0$. So the answer is yes/no according to whether $G\ast G_0$ is isomorphic to $G_0$. And by Grushko's theorem (see next paragraph), the latter holds if and only $G$ is a trivial group. So we get a contradiction.

[Grushko's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grushko_theorem) says that the generating rank (minimal number of generators) of a free product $B\ast C$ equals the sum of the generating ranks of $B$ and $C$. (This is false for direct products: if $B$ and $C$ are cyclic of order $2$ and $3$, then the generating rank of $B$, $C$, $B\times C$ are all equal to $1$.) In particular, for every finitely generated group $B$ and every group $C$, the free product $B\ast C$ is isomorphic to $B$ if and only if $C$ is a trivial group.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.